# Dynamic textbox alignment

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a button which will create additional textboxes when clicked. The problem is that i dont get them aligned with the default box of company code.

```
  public System.Windows.Forms.TextBox Addcompcode()
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txt = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.Controls.Add(txt);
            txt.Top = A * 123;
            txt.Left = 90;
            txt.Text = "Company Code";
            A = A + 1;
            return txt;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following vertical alignment

```
this.txt.VerticalAlignment = VerticalTextAlignment.Top;
```